# update a property by multi-thread with Etag in Table Storage azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

**overview:**
When I upload blob in blob storage under container/productID(folder)/blobName, then event-subscription saves this event in storage queue. After that azure function polls this event and does the following:

> 1- read from the corresponding table the current count property (how
> many blobs are stored under productID(folder))
>
> 2- increase the count + 1
>
> 3- write it back in the corresponding table
>
> 4- return

**The problem** is a race condition, I tried to put it in Lock() as shown in code. That works when I upload 1000 files at the same time. But if I load 10000 files at the same time and read the count attr, it returns more than 10000 which is false, it must return only 10000. i have also prevented the scaling out only one instance is created.
Is the problem still by a race condition(i don't think that but could be) or could be that Azure runtime runs the event on the function more than one? I am not sure what is happening. Any ideas will be good

```
class _tableStorage:
    def __init__(self, account, key):
        self.table_service = TableService(account, key)

    def create_table(self, table_name):
        self.table_service.create_table(table_name)

    def insert_entity_table(self, table_name, entity):
        self.table_service.insert_or_replace_entity(table_name, entity)

    def exist_table(self, table_name):
        return self.table_service.exists(table_name)

    def get_entity_table(self, table_name, entity):
        return self.table_service.get_entity(
            table_name, entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey)

    def get_all_entities_table(self, table_name):
        try:
            list = self.table_service.query_entities(table_name)
        except:
            logging.info('unknown error by listing entities')
        return list


def get_blob_meta(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    return {
        "storage": parsed_url.netloc.split('.')[0],
        "contianer": parsed_url.path.split('/')[1],
        "folder": parsed_url.path.split('/')[2]
    }


threadLock = threading.Lock()


def main(msg: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
    url = json.loads(msg.get_body().decode(
        'utf-8').replace("'", "\""))['data']['url']
    logging.info(url)
    blob_meta = get_blob_meta(url)
    logging.info(blob_meta)
    table_service = _tableStorage(
        blob_meta['storage'],
        "xxxxxxxxxx")

    threadLock.acquire()
    entity = Entity()
    # should have same partition to be stored in one node.
    entity.PartitionKey = blob_meta['contianer']
    entity.RowKey = blob_meta['folder']
    if(not table_service.exist_table(blob_meta['contianer'])):
        table_service.create_table(blob_meta['contianer'])
        entity.count = 1
    else:
        entity.count = table_service.get_entity_table(
            blob_meta['contianer'], entity).count + 1

    table_service.insert_entity_table(blob_meta['contianer'], entity)
    threadLock.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two solution:**

**first one with multi-threading:**

idea is ETag flag in header to ensure atomic processing. at first, i read the count property and ETag flag. Then, i increment it. before I update the count property with the incremented one in the table, if_match will match my Etag with the stored one in the table, if the ETag matched, then the count will be updated, otherwise, it throws an error, i catch this error and try again with reading and incrementing until the update is successful
[To understand more read the docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmosdb-table/azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice.tableservice?view=azure-python#merge-entity-table-name--entity--if-match------timeout-none-)

```
 header_etag = "random-etag"
    response_etag = "random-response"
    while True:
        sleep(random.random())  # sleep between 0 and 1 second.
        header = table_service1.get_entity(
            client_table, client_table, client_product)
        header_etag = header['etag']
        new_count = header['Count'] + 1
        entity_product = create_product_entity(
            client_table, client_product, new_count, client_image_table)
        try:
            response_etag = table_service1.merge_entity(client_table, entity_product,
                                                        if_match=header_etag)
            break
        except:
            logging.info("race condition detected")
```

**Second one**

**Solved by preventing multi-thread:**

**local debugging** in local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {

    "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__queues__batchSize": 1,
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__queues__newBatchThreshold": 0,

  }
}
```

**in production ** host.json

```
 "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "batchSize": 1,
            "newBatchThreshold": 0
        }
    }
```

[To understand pls see the documentation of microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---concurrency)